# Como puedo hacer la animación de estas pantallas así como en la imagen? Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, programación-móvil, sdk, screen

Hola estoy intentando hacer una aplicación, la primera pantalla la logré hacer, sin embargo, la segunda pantalla o bueno la del registro debe salir hasta la mitad, ahí se deben llenar los datos y demás. Como puedo hacer eso en flutter, que la pantalla salga desde abajo, cuando oprimo el btn. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quizás esto te ayude: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYhDgg1fowY

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un paquete que te ayuda con eso [modal bottom sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) luego que haces el import en la clase, puedes utilizar este tipo de modal:

```
RaisedButton(
     onPressed: abrirModal, 
     child: Text('abrir modal'),
   );
```

Ahora creas el método que es el que estás llamando en la propiedad `onPressed`:

```
void abrirModal(){
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context){
      return Padding(
         padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
         child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
             Text('MODAL BOTTOM SHEET'),
             SizedBox(height: 25),
             Text('MODAL BOTTOM SHEET'),
          ]),
       );
    }
  )
}
```

De todos modos lee la documentación de este paquete, te va a ser muy útil por las propiedades que tiene.

Comment: Hola, me ha servido muchísimo tu ayuda, tengo una duda extra ¿Como hago para que el modal se agrande más? solo me llega hasta la mitad, quisiera que pasara mas de la mitad

Comment: Puedes encerrar la columna en un SizedBox y a ese SizedBox aplicarle la altura algo asi:  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65, me comentas si te sirve